# Multiple Condition in R code

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Suppose, I have a data set like,

```
y <- c(0,0,1,2,2,1,0,1)
a <- c(0,2,1,1,0,2,0,3)
dat <- data.frame(y, a)
```

I want to calculate the value of `f <- digamma(a+y)` by using the condition

```
if(a>0 & y==0) then f
if(a==0 & y>0) then f
if (a==0 & y==0) then f = 1
```

How can I do it using R code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will give you what you're after post hoc:

```
f <- digamma(a+y) 
f[a==0 & y==0] <- 1
```

or

```
f[is.nan(f)] <- 1
```

Well this is using indexing to see which elements in the vector are nan or in the first method both a and y are 0.  Then the index `[]` says take these elements of f and the assignment `<-` says make these elements a one.

Comment: Basically in R code "digamma(0)" gives "NaN". Can you give me the detail solution?

Comment: See my explanation.  This is information that can be found in one of R's introductory manuals.

Comment: @Rudro88, building on Tyler's concept, you can also use an `ifelse` statement like the following `with(dat, ifelse(is.nan(digamma(a + y)), 1, digamma(a + y)))`. Here, I've referred to the `data.frame` you've created, rather than the objects `a` and `y` that you created to create the `data.frame`.

Comment: I just noticed the dataframe and realized its part of a later edit, not part of the original question.  Originally it was in one vector.  I used to use `ifelse` a ton but really don't anymore.  I must have gravitated towards using the assignment to logical indexing.